# Computing python using GPU

Tags: python, gpu

I have the following python scripts made by me. I am wondering if by any chance it can be adjusted to use the gpu computing capabilities. What it does: generates a random 64 characters hash (a to f, 0 to 9) using the secrets.token_hex(32) function and then it applies it to a set of defined rules with known outcome and if it matches all the rules it outputs the matching hash into a file if not it writes the wrong hash in another file. I want to do it using the gpu for much faster computation. Best regards.

```
import random
import hashlib
import secrets

def writeFile(addString):
    txtFile = open("NOTFOUND.txt", 'a')
    txtFile.write(addString)
    txtFile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    whileLoopBreak = True
    txtFileRead = open("NOTFOUND.txt", 'a')
    checkIfExist = 0
    public_seed = 3314371705
    roundList = ['1176881', '1176882', '1176883', '1176884', '1176885']
    while whileLoopBreak:
        tempString = secrets.token_hex(32)
        txtFileRead = open("NOTFOUND.txt", 'r')
        for line in txtFileRead:
            while tempString == line[0:-1]:
                if(tempString != line[0:-1]):
                    break
                tempString = secrets.token_hex(32)
        txtFileRead.close()
        writeFile(tempString + "\n")
        for i in range(0, 5):
            hashString = tempString + "-" + str(public_seed) + "-" + roundList[i]
            hash_object = hashlib.sha256(hashString.encode())
            hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()
            begToEnd = hex_dig[0:8]
            intFromBTE = int(begToEnd, 16) % 15
            if intFromBTE == 10 and roundList[i] == roundList[0]:##1
                checkIfExist += 1
            elif intFromBTE == 4 and roundList[i] == roundList[1]:##2
                checkIfExist += 1
            elif intFromBTE == 12 and roundList[i] == roundList[2]:##3
                checkIfExist += 1
            elif intFromBTE == 6 and roundList[i] == roundList[3]:##4
                checkIfExist += 1
            elif intFromBTE == 8 and roundList[i] == roundList[4]:##5
                checkIfExist += 1  
        if checkIfExist == 5:
            checkIfExist = 0
            txtFile = open("serverSeedFound.txt", 'a')
            txtFile.write(tempString + "\n")
            print(tempString)
            txtFile.close()
        else:
            checkIfExist = 0
```